Perhaps add a superfluous About link in each StackExchange's home page three bar menu
Visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .
We see a logo, "Cross Validated". That's nice, but doesn't quite tell us what the site is all about.
Feeling rather uneasy, we look around for some "about" link. None.
In final desperation, we look in the URL bar, and see "stats.".
OK, this must be about statistics.

Well you should have known that else you would not have navigated to that site.

I don't recall how I navigated to that site. Some link in some Google search result probably.

Well then you were searching for statistics in the first place, so you can only blame yourself.

But I even pressed the three bar menu and "Home" in there. Plenty of room in that menu for "About".

Don't you see that question mark button with the circle around it on the upper right? Push it! Voila.
